# How to translate android strings with arguments with Google translate API?

Tags: android, google-translate

I need to translate a lot of phrases with arguments and special chars in many languages. But I get some garbage in the place, where arguments are. For example:

> Amount will be funded: %1$s %4$s\nTax: %2$s %4$s\nTotal amount: %3$s %4$s\nDo you agree?

If I translate it in Russian, I get:

> "Сумма будет финансироваться:**% 1 $ S% 4 $ S \ n**Tax:**% 2 $ S% 4 $ S \ N**total количество:**% 3 $ S% 4 $ S \ n**Вы согласны?

I've highlighted text, which became ugly and not parcelable. I have read manuals, but no one showed me how to point special chars and phrases not to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way. Translate without "%" and then add them manually.

Comment: After I choose you answer best, I find some solution. I replace arguments with UTF-8 untranslateble chars, for example with smiles. All translations leave these chars